# Empty String < 0 when being cast implicitly?

Tags: php, string, casting, integer

I've learned (the hard way) that `"" < 0` evaluates to `bool(true)`, while `(int)"" < 0` evaluates to `bool(false)` and never questioned it really, but now want to know why (and why it had been different before PHP8).

Not only is it counter intuitive but also seems to be not in line with the documentation. For comparative contexts [this table](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.types) is being shown, which suggests that any `string` will implicitly be cast to a number, if the other operand is of type `string`, `resource`, `int` or `float`, so I'm expecting `"" < 0` to evaluate to `bool(false)`, because `(int)""` evaluates to `int(0)`.

```php
var_dump('' < 0);
// bool(true)

var_dump((int)'' < 0);
// bool(false)

var_dump('' < 0.0);
// bool(true)

var_dump((float)'' < 0.0);
// bool(false)
```

Comment: Not 100% about the dupe answering the question - but closing this is more about trying to keep any solutions to a very specific question in one place.

Comment: @NigelRen It does point me to the right direction, at least. Thank you.

Comment: With the change you're now comparing `'' < '0'` which is true, whereas before you were comparing `0 < 0` which is false.

Comment: Thank you @Nick. So I guess the table in the docs (linked in my question) is just outdated now. Other pages are linking the that particular table directly, but there is a warning if you scroll to the very top.

Comment: @volkerschulz yeah, it's unfortunate that that warning doesn't explain how the processing is now done in PHP8, only how it used to be done prior.

Comment: Makes you wonder if PHP should have strict `<`, `>`, `<=` and `>=` operators as well.

Comment: And the worst part is that `'1' == '0001'` is still true...

Comment: I developed a habit of casting explicitly whenever I can and will maintain that habit probably. It came up just yesterday here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77360637/change-user-role-based-on-custom-user-metadata-value-in-woocommerce/77361122?noredirect=1#comment136382556_77361122 which made me want to get to the bottom of that matter. I even got flagged for harassment, because I told them that `""<0` evaluates to `true`. :D

Comment: `And the worst part is that '1' == '0001' is still true` - Didn't expect that either. So the learning here is: Cast explicitly and compare strictly whenever possible.